# Cassandra is not consistent despite QUORUM consistency level with replication factor 3

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver, consistency

I have a problem with Cassandras consistency. I have 3 Cassandra nodes (Version 2.0.14.352) in the cluster and I am reading and writting with **consistency level QUORUM** and my **replicationfactor is 3**. 
If I understand [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html) right in my case Cassandra should be consistent, because 2+2>3. But I wrote a test in java, where I insert some data very fast into the cassandra using the datastax-driver:

```
final Instant t1 = Instant.parse("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
final Instant t2 = Instant.parse("2000-02-01T00:00:00.000Z");

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    dataProvider.setValue(t1, new Double(1));
    //If the next line is removed, the test will pass
    dataProvider.setValue(t2, new Double(3));

    dataProvider.saveToDB();
    dataProvider.clear();
    assertEquals("i=" + i, new Double(3), dataProvider.getValue(t2));
    assertEquals("i=" + i, new Double(1), dataProvider.getValue(t1));

    dataProvider.setValue(t1, new Double(2));
    dataProvider.saveToDB();
    dataProvider.clear();
    assertEquals("i=" + i, new Double(2), dataProvider.getValue(t1));

    dataProvider.setValue(t1, new Double(101));
    dataProvider.saveToDB();
    dataProvider.clear();
    assertEquals("i=" + i, new Double(101), dataProvider.getValue(t1));
}
```

with the corresponding table

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.table(
  id text,
  year int,
  month int,
  time timestamp,
  value double,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id, year, month), time)
)
```

dataProvider.setValue() internaly puts the given value into a NavigableMap. dataProvider.saveToDB() inserts the data into Cassandra. Here I tried on the one hand to insert the data asynchronous and waited until all ResultSetFuture finished and on the other hand I executed the statements synchronous. But this effected only the performance. In detail the save method looks like

```
final List<ResultSetFuture> sets = newLinkedList();
Batch batch = QueryBuilder.batch();
int batchsize=0;
for (Map.Entry<Instant, Double> entry : valueMap) {
    final Instant instant = entry.getKey();
    final ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    final Date date = Date.from(instant);
    final Insert insert = QueryBuilder.insertInto(table)
            .value(ID, id)
            .value(YEAR, zonedDateTime.getYear())
            .value(MONTH, zonedDateTime.getMonthValue())
            .value(TIME, date)
            .value(VALUE, entry.getValue());
    batch.add(insert);
    ++batchsize;
    if(batchsize % 200 == 0){
        sets.add(cassandraConnector.executeAsync(batch));
        batch = QueryBuilder.batch();
    }
}
if(batchsize % 200 != 0) { //es gibt noch nicht abgeschickte Statements
    sets.add(cassandraConnector.executeAsync(batch));
}
cassandraConnector.waitForFinish(sets);
```

cassandraConnector manages the connection. I am waiting until all ResultSets finished with

```
public boolean waitForFinish(List<ResultSetFuture> sets) {
    ResultSet result = null;
    for (final ResultSetFuture resultSetFuture : sets) {
        // Wait until finished
        try {
            result = resultSetFuture.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            resultSetFuture.cancel(true);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (result != null) {
                ExecutionInfo executionInfo = result.getExecutionInfo();
                System.out.println("Timout from server with IP: " + executionInfo.getTriedHosts());
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The curiosity is, that if I remove the line under the comment, the test will pass and it doesn´t matter how often I execute it. But if I run the test without removing the line sometimes it fails in the first loop, but sometimes it runs 3 loop until it fails. Furthermore it fails always at different lines. For example

```
java.lang.AssertionError: i=0 
Expected :101
Actual   :2
```

I also got

```
java.lang.AssertionError: i=2
Expected :2
Actual   :101
```

So it seems that Cassandra wrote the 1 and after that instead of writting the 2 Cassandra recovered the 101 i wrote before the 1. Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior? Why does the test pass if I remove the line? I am writting to different partitions. I tried to change the consistency level to ALL but the behavior didn´t change.

Comment: Can you also show the code for DataProvider class?

Comment: I´ve added some more code. There you can see how I create and execute the statements.

Comment: This looks like the common Batch Misunderstanding
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317877/cassandra-batch-statement-execution-order

Comment: But if I leave out the batch and execute each insert synchronous, the result is the same. Furthermore in the test the batch is only containing 2 inserts which are inserting 1 value to 2 different partitions. After this has finished I override the values.

Comment: I tried to reimplement the `DataProvider` class from your telling, but the the test is OK here. What does the `clear` method do? How do you run your code to achieve the "insert some data very fast " goal?

Comment: Why don't you use Guava's `Futures.allAsList` method instead of your `waitForFinish`? Why do you need a `NavigableMap` and not standard `Map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Obviously the clocks are not 100 % synchronous. When I create the insert statement I added **.using(timestamp(System.nanoTime() / 1000));** and now the test passes.